# Multiple instanceof keyword usage a good programming methodology

Tags: java

I am trying a piece of code in the way below which provide validation to  the variables of the particular class only using a single method `validateParams()` and calling it at different parts of program wherever required.  We can say that `doSomething()` method is the starting method of a web application.

There are no dependencies among these classes `Car`, `Computer` and `Mobile`. I only like to carry out validation using a single method instead of multiple methods for each class

```
public void doSomething() {
    validateParams(car);
    statement1...... 
    statement2.....

    validateParams(computer);
    statement3.....

    validateParams(mobile);
}

private void validateParams(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Car){ 
       //Validate variables related to obj  
    } 
    else if(obj instanceof Computer){ 
       //Validate variables related to obj  
    } 
    else if(obj instanceof Mobile){
      //Validate variables related to obj  
    }

    // There are many if loops
}
```

I am thinking that I am doing some kind of wrong activity of using `instanceof` and validating in this way. Switch case could look very good but it won't allow objects. Is there anyway I can handle this programming using lambda expression. I am new to Java 8 and I find the use of lambda expressions tricky.

Comment: I would create an interface with one validate method, then let all the classes implement that interface, implement the validate method in each class, and then just call that method in your validateParams method. That's much cleaner than your approach.

Comment: @dunni.Cant change the classes now as it is a large legacy web application. I am just adding a new validation method and dropping few classes in it.

Comment: Explicit casts are always a sign of trouble. If you explain the use case in actual detail, it may be easier to help; JSR-303 is always the preferable option when it will work.

Comment: @is my approach Good one

Comment: @Chris: what is JSR-303. I have declared the method as private. So it won't be accessible outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options. One would be to let the objects do the validation themselves using an interface that requires a `validate()` method as pointed out in the comments by @dunni.

If you definitely need your validation to be performed outside of the individual classes without changing any of their implementation you could use method overloading. Create multiple functions called

```
private void validateParams(Type obj)
```

with the respective type of the object to validate and implement the specific validation for that type in there. So you'd have methods like:

```
private void validateParams(Computer computer) {...}
private void validateParams(Car car) {...}
private void validateParams(Mobile mobile) {...}
```

and you can call all of them using:

```
validateParams(obj) // where obj is of type Computer, Car or Mobile
```

Comment: I got an idea for this approach but there will be huge number of methods in a single class

Comment: @niks But having multiple smaller methods that focus on the validation of an instance of a specific type is a lot cleaner and easier to test than cramming the whole validation code for complelety unrelated classes into the same method. Your single method will have roughly the same length as the individual methods combined.

Comment: @niks with the instanceof method there would bw a hihe number of ifs in a single class

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I remember the similar question from yesterday.  C-:=

So, as I said yesterday, it is almost always a bad practice to declare a function that accepts parameters of type `Object`. Functions that accept `Object` parameters are only found in framework-level or system-level programming.  And when doing framework-level or system-level programming, you have no notion of application-level entities, so you don't know of any `Car`, `Computer` or `Mobile`, so there is no possibility to use `instanceof` like this.

Generally, any use of `instanceof` is a sign of something being done wrongly.  The industry term for this is "code smell".

There are extremely few and very specific cases where passing an `Object` argument and using `instanceof` is necessary and appropriate, as for example when coding a `boolean equals( Object other )` method.  Whenever you see `Object` arguments and `instanceof` outside of these very few well known cases, it is a code smell.  Don't do it.

I would insist that in order for your code not to smell, you would need to come up with a common base class.  Yesterday's example involved `Car`, `Motorcycle` and `Bicycle`, and I suggested coming up with a `Vehicle` base class.  Now you have chosen the classes to be `Car`, `Computer`, and `Mobile` in an effort to indicate that they share no common functionality.  I would suggest that:

1. Either these classes really share no common functionality, in which case passing them as `Object` and using `instanceof` is bad practice, certainly to be viewed as code smell and not pass any code review in the industry, or
2. There is still some way to extract a common base class (or interface) which can declare a `validate()` method so as to avoid passing `Object` arguments and using `instanceof`. It could be `Gadget`, or `MyWorldEntity`, or `Validatable`.

Comment: Understood very well. But I think I can't change the classes now

Comment: Is there anyway to use lambda expression

Comment: I don't think a lambda expression would accomplish anything here.  But wait and see if someone comes up with any ideas.

Comment: I worked with an addon system some time ago, where most of the events where passed to the functions as `<base system name>Event` and you didn't know what the actual type of them were, so you had to use long if chains.It was a mess and you basically had to write singleton eventmanager classes yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There should be absolutely no reason to deal with three completely different objects in the same method. You should define an interface (for example `Validateable`) and put a validate method in it:

```
interface Validateable {
    public void validate();
}
```

Then make the classes implement it

```
class Car implements Validateable { ... }
```

Comment: How do you validate like `car != null`?

Comment: @saka1029 `if (car != null) car.validate();`